# UITextView becomes transparent in some parts iOS

Tags: ios, uitextview, alpha

I have a view, say 400 x 400, and a UITextView as its subview, which covers the complete superview.

Superview background color is black, with alpha as 0.7.
UItextView background color is black, with alpha 0.0.

Now when some view_behind disappears behind the text view, probably with animation, the part of the whole superview that lied above the view_behind becomes transparent. Including the text on the UITextView.
It also happens when volume is changed and the volume hub disappears. Some part of the view becomes transparent.
(By transparent I mean that alpha is 0, and the underlying view is completely visible through that transparent part.)

Now if I increase the alpha of the text view to some 0.7 or 1.0, then the transparency doesn't occur.

If I call `[self.view setNeedsLayout]` transparency disappears.

Sometimes transparency disappears with time. Also when the device orientation changes, the transparency disappears.

**Edit:**
Camera us running, which becomes visible once some view (of the same size as the transparent rectangle) disappears behind the UITextView. (The "Hello World" is a different UILabel which background color as black with alpha 0.0, and the message part is a UITextView with background color as black with alpha 0.0)

[image: Camera running on the background is visible]

**Edit:** Transparency doesn't occur if the view disappears without any animation.

Comment: Add some screenshots, it's not clear what the problem is

Comment: If I take snapshot of the screen using lock+home combo, the transparency disappears. I'll try taking pictures using some other device..

Comment: Make a screenshot using XCode organizer

Comment: If I use xcode organizer to take screen shot, screenshot comes fine! I have captured screen snapshot using some other device which I'' be uploading now